# What is the difference between the phrases "data transferred" and "transferred data"?

Tags: past-tense, past-participles

What's the difference in meaning between the phrases "data transfered" and "transfered data"?

The role of the "verb + -ed" combination in a sentence always confuses me.

Answer (score 4):

> What's the meaning differs from "data transfered" [sic] to "transfered [sic] data".

First, the correct spelling is "transferred."

It would be best to have used them in a sentence. Here are some examples:

1. The transferred data totaled 2.5 GB.
2. The data transferred totaled 2.5 GB.
3. The computer transferred data at a high speed.

**"Transferred" conjugated as a past participle**

In both examples #1 and #2, which have the same meaning, the word "transferred" is conjugated as a past participle of the English verb "transfer." A past participle is typically formed by adding the suffix -ed to the lexical (root) form of the verb. Thus, transfer + -ed = transferred.

A participle can function in a sentence as an adjective modifying a noun (attributively), a predicate (predicatively), or a noun (substantively).

Examples of the past participle "transferred" functioning in each manner:

1. Attributively or adjectivally:

The transferred data was also encrypted by a complex algorithm.

2. Predicatively:

The data is transferred, so now we can finish the remainder of our tasks.

3. Substantively:

If we look at the graph, the amount of the transferred far exceeded that of the non-transferred.

**"Transferred" conjugated as a past tense verb**

In example #3, the word "transferred" is a verb conjugated in the past tense. Like a past participle, a past tense verb is also formed by adding the suffix -ed to the lexical (root) form of a verb.

Subject - the computer

Verb - transferred

Direct object - data

<sub>Participles are actually more complex than I discussed. I offered the basics which I thought were necessary.</sub>

**To answer your question**, the two phrases "data transferred" and "transferred data" can mean the same thing if "transferred" functions as a past participle in both sentences. In other words, it all depends on how the rest of the sentence is constructed.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is grammatical.

In "data transferred", "transferred"  is the past participle; a verb.

In "transferred data", "transferred" is either a simple past verb (as in *I transferred data elsewhere*) or an adjective (*The transferred data is 5 GB large.*)